# What is the app/templates directory for when using Yeoman?

Tags: yeoman

As the title suggests I want to know what the app/templates directory is for when using Yeoman.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yeoman team member here.

It's simply meant to put your templates in. Like your Handlebar.js templates or Mustache, etc.

Nothing magic happens when you do, at least not yet. Just a best practice we wanted to enforce.

Comment: I think he's looking for more than this.

Comment: I answered the question. There's nothing more to it. Not sure what more he was looking for...

Comment: FWIW I wasn't the one who downvoted you. But have a +1 for your helpful edit